# Where are injected domain class methods like isDirty, save, etc defined in Grails / GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a problem where isDirty isn't recognizing that an object has changed, even though I can see very clearly via a debugger that it has. I'd like to take a look at the source, but I can't seem to track the source down, and the debugger won't step into it (I assume because it's handled through some sort of AST magic).

I checked out git-core, but "find . -type f | xargs grep -il isDirty" yields no results.

Where can I track this code down?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/mapping/engine/NativeEntryEntityPersister.java but note that there might be a more direct Hibernate implementation, since the functionality was originally Hibernate-specific but is now abstracted in the GORM API

Comment: Thanks Burt. I'll give that a try in the morning. I'm curious.... Is this class and the way it's injected into a domain class documented anywhere?

Comment: I doubt it. grails-data-mapping is a large project with several sub-projects. In general though, each GORM impl does implement the core interfaces and there's a TCK that each has to pass, so there is a structure to it all.

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll be helpful, but the ASTs wire in the methods from GormInstanceApi, GormStaticApi, and GormValidationApi, and individual GORM impls may subclass those (currently only the Hibernate impls do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASTs wire in the methods from `GormInstanceApi` (and `GormStaticApi`, `GormValidationApi`, etc.) and individual GORM implementations may subclass those (currently only the Hibernate implementations do).

For example, the Hibernate 3 implementation is [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate/src/main/groovy/org/grails/orm/hibernate/HibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy#L65) and the Hibernate 4 implementation is in class of the same name in the [grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/tree/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4) project (most of the Hibernate code is in the [grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/tree/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core) project, but due to changed interfaces some is in the two top-level projects).

Comment: So with these wired methods, is it possible to put a breakpoint in something like intellij and have it stop? If not, any other way to hook into them? The isDirty behavior I'm seeing (hibernate4) is very odd.